# Can you use a SAS fan-out cable to connect more drives?

Tags: storage, network-attached-storage, sas, hba

I bought a Broadcom 9400-16e HBA that has four external ports. I was hoping that by using four mini-SAS cables that fan-out to two, I could double the number of connected drives from 16 to 32. However, each fan-out cable can only detect four drives, two per mini-sas instead of four.

I seem to have misunderstood their capability. I understood the throughput would be half for each mini-SAS, but didn't expect they'd only address half the number of drives each.

Is there a storcli command I can run so that each port at the HBA can address 8 drives using the fan-out cables? Or do I need to buy some expanders?

Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason you are not trying to use SAS as intended, with a backplane?

Comment: What the question is calling for is certainly not a *reasonable business practice*.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is for home use. I have a couple 24-drive ZFS pools. Because I'm unable to have a 4u chassis shipped here, I've been connecting 8-bay NAS enclosures via SAS cables. The enclosures have a "backplane" that is just SAS connectors for the drives, and SATA connectors on the other side. Have been using mini-SAS to SATA breakout cables.

Anyway, ended up buying an expander for each enclosure.

Answer (score 0):

This is a server with 4 external mini-SAS ports, going to separate JBOD enclosures. I've bought a SAS expander for each JBOD.